# ​ Is it safe to travel to Istanbul/Turkey in the summer of 2016?

Tags: safety, turkey, event-based-effects

​After these number of explosions in different cities in Turkey, including an explosion at the heart of Istanbul’s old city, an area visited by up to 14 million tourists each year. Is it still safe to travel to Istanbul ?
As for me, I've already bought my plane ticket for my next visit (in summer 2016), and I'm looking forward to it. but now, I became really worried and confused. Should I just forget all these explosions and travel or should I cancel my ticket and seeking another place to travel ?

Comment: This might be a difficult question to answer. 'Being safe' is quite subjective. But you could look at it this way: 13 people out of 14 million a  year died, the odds are very slim that it'd be you. (It's literally 1 in a million) You're much more likely getting [killed by a car](http://www.dailysabah.com/nation/2015/07/24/traffic-accidents-kill-more-than-1500-in-6-months). Based on the above numbers, even if you happened to be in that area on the day of the attack, there's only a chance in 3000 that you'd get killed. So only yourself are able to tell, whether that's a risk you want to take.

Comment: Would you be scared of travelling to Israel because of Hamas? If the answer is yes, then I would suggest not travelling to Turkey right now, if the answer is no, then no problems. It is true that there is a security breach due to the lack of proper governance, however if you take personal precautions (avoiding large groups and public transportation), you should be safe. There are 15mil registered (total 20 mil) people living in Istanbul, and they continue to live there, so you would be safe.

Comment: You are worried about Istanbul. Would you travel to Paris, London, Stockholm, Oslo, or Madrid? There have been terrorist attacks there in the last few years (London and Paris in the last year).